# No sln file in MVC project. Any way to generate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am supposed to take over a project which is MVC based. in the source code folder, I see all the required files except the sln file. Is there a way to generate the sln file for MVC project? Will it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project has the `.csproj` file, then open the `.csproj` file with Visual Studio, then when you close VS it will ask you to save a .sln file.

Comment: Thanks that is working. But If I create a new MVC application and add all the existing files, will the project work as expected?

Comment: If you create a brand new web application MVC or other type using Visual Studio, it will save a sln for you, and yes it should work fine.